# Measure for filling in blanks between two tables

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

tried to figure this one myself to no luck and couldn't find similar problem through Google.

I have a number of tables within PowerBI dashboard, one table is a stock table that has values for random dates throughout the month, what i am trying to figure out is, how can i use dates from DayDim table(that has all dates for a month) in a table view and have a measure that would fill in missing dates with the most recent value from the stock table.

Please see a simplified representation as per image attached.

Of course in that stock table i have numerous products and customers etc. for each of those dates, so i would need to have the ability to still calculate values within those contexts, rather than just a total value number.

any help greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

[image: Simplified example screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you realy need this you can go with an extra column on your Day Dim table (or create a new table).

```
Value = LOOKUPVALUE(stock[Value];stock[Stock Date]; 
    CALCULATE(MAX('Day Dim Table'[Date]);
        FILTER('Day Dim Table';'Day Dim Table'[Date] <=EARLIER('Day Dim Table'[Date]) && RELATED(stock[Value]) <> BLANK())))
```

Please ensure you create a relation on date between the 2 tables.

I do wonder why you need it because I do not see the point of creating extra data but then again, I do not know your requirements..

Comment: nah, that wouldn't work, maybe i oversimplified the example: stock table has various lines for the same day, i.e. different products and customers, and i would need to be able to calculate it within those context/filters. the reason behind this kind of duplication is because i have a bunch of other tables for each date and i am doing a table on all tables in one view, and with this set having gaps i cannot represent data in one table showing the stock value for the missing dates AND being able to filter on particular product/customer. Thank you for the effort.